# Blink effect when receiving new data

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a "search for games" application where I use jQuery to automatically fetch new game requests via PHP which prints out rows from a MySQL table.

What I want to do is make new requests blink for a few seconds, perhaps in red color or something. How can I do this with jQuery? I suppose I have to compare the data in some way, but not sure how.

Answer (score 9):

either as travelboy said or you can do this:

```
$('.className Or #elementId').fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400).fadeOut(400).fadeIn(400);
```

I use this myself on my own website and it works perfectly. The script isn't pretty but it will do the job.

**Update**
For people who wants to use a more jQuery-way, use below code to achieve the same effect.

```
$.fn.blink = function (speed, blink) {
    var options = {
        xSpeed: speed ? speed : 400, // Set the blink speed
        xBlink: blink ? blink : 5 // Set how many times the element should blink
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < options.xBlink; i++) {
        this.fadeOut(options.xSpeed);
        this.fadeIn(options.xSpeed);
    }
    return this; // To support jQuery chain-ability
};
```

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $('#MyDiv').blink(600, 3);
});
```

Example using chain-ability:

```
$(function() {
    $('#MyDiv').blink(600, 3).css("background-color", "green");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

- When new data comes in, give the elements representing this new data a class.

`$('#theElementContainingNewText').addClass('blinking');`

- Write a function that selects all elements having your blinking class and toggles their visibility
- Use the function setInterval to periodically call the toggle function every 500ms or so

`setInterval(function(){$('.blinking').toggle();},500);`

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#theElement").click(function() {
        $("#ContainingNewText").animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```